# create Blogs programmatically sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

in sharepoint 2007, how to create blogs programmatically?
Regards,
Abhimanyu

Comment: what is the problem you are facing it should be done the way you right to some other list

Comment: are there blogs in SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Your question is not clear, Do you want to create blogs using Object Model or by using Out of Box blog functionality of SharePoint...

Comment: I want to create blogs using object model.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint lcid = web.Language;
SPWeb web2 = web.Webs.Add("Blog", "Blog", "Blog", lcid, web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(lcid)["BLOG#0"], false, false);
```